# Overleaf: \includepdf causing compilation timeout (due to an infinite loop)

Tags: errors, pdf, overleaf, pdfpages, compilation-error

I just added a PDF in my Overleaf project (created by myself from Samsung Notes, never had a problem before) and adding this pdf using

```
\includepdf[pages=-]{Tp12.pdf}
```

(see pictures below) with

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

caused me a timeout error:

[image: timeout error]

Here is my pdf's location (the two first never caused any problem, and are not shorter).

[image: pdf location]

This pdf has a size of 4,97 Mo.

Here is my head declaration in main.tex:

```
\documentclass{report}

\sceau{Pictures/sceau.jpg}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}
  {\endminipage\par\medskip}
  
  \usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=teal,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={Overleaf Example},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
    }

\urlstyle{same}

\definecolor{RED}{RGB}{247,197,197}
\definecolor{GREEN}{RGB}{197,247,232}
\definecolor{GREEN_OCTAVE}{RGB}{68,200,81}
\definecolor{BLUE}{RGB}{197,232,247}
\definecolor{GRAY}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{lilas}{RGB}{238, 130, 238}

%+++++++++++New Commands++++++++++++
\newcommand{\bc}{\begin{center}}
\newcommand{\ec}{\end{center}}
\newcommand{\be}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\ee}{\end{equation}}
\def\bi{\begin{enumerate}}
 \def\ei{\end{enumerate}}
 \newcommand{\dst}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\ba}{\begin{array}}
\newcommand{\ea}{\end{array}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\K}{\mathbb{K}}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\Ra}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\lra}{\longrightarrow}
\newcommand{\Lra}{\Longrightarrow}
\newcommand{\Eq}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\Leq}{\Longleftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\Lagr}{\mathcal{L}}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
```

I hope I gave everything you need. I can't share the whole project for privacy issues.

Comment: what do you expect anyone here can say? The system has a timelimit so any big enough project will give that error. It is not a tex error it is just a commercial decision to limit the processing time unless you pay more.

Comment: The documentclass **report** doesn't define `\sceau`, so `\sceau` can't occur right after `\documentclass` without triggering error-messages. Seems `\addbibresource` right before `\begin{document}` is not defined by any of the packages exhibited in your preamble. I doubt you gave sufficient information. Portions of code not revealed might form a never ending tail-recursive loop or provide another reason for reaching processing-time-limit. How can one know? If `\includepdf[pages=-]{Tp12.pdf}` is all you added, then reaching the processing-time limit is likely not to be due to a TeX-related bug.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this pdf is less that 5 Mo, I'm far from reaching the overleaf limit ! The compilation time was of 5 seconds before, how can one pdf make it last more than 1 minute ??

Comment: @UlrichDiez is there anything I can do ?

Comment: @EmileCouzin Overleaf is just a Web-Interface for calling the TeX-program of some release of the TeX-Distribution TeX Live via internet. (Afaik with Overleaf they use some Ubuntu docker-image. Which Ubuntu depends on which release of Tex Live you select after clicking "Menu" on the top-left corner of the window of the browser where overleaf is displayed.)You can look at the error-messages written by the TeX-compiler to the .log-file  by clicking the symbol for "Logs and output files" at the right of the "Recompile" button and then clicking "Expand" in the field "Raw logs".  If this reveals ...

Comment: @EmileCouzin ... If this reveals that the reaching of the processtime-limit is not due to a bug in your TeX-code but is due to the hugeness of your project, consider installing/using a TeX Distribution on your local machine instead of using overleaf via internet.

Comment: Thank you for those informations, but the project wan't big at all ! As you can see it in the answer the problem came from another fact

Comment: Andreas has uploaded a new version to ctan that will not loop forever here (alhough that will not be on overleaf until the next texlive update)

Comment: @EmileCouzin I did not exclude the problem being due to another fact. I even explained how in Overleaf to view the .log-file produced by the TeX-compiler in order to find out about such facts. David Carlisle pointed out in his answer that by viewing the .log-file you can find out about the fact of TeX not finding the file whose inclusion  should be triggered by `\includepdf` leading to unsuccessful but time-consuming cascades of attempts of recovering...  When it comes to recovery from errors/unexpected behavior one of the most value sources of information is the TeX-compiler's .log-file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your example to

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

aaa

\includepdf[pages=-]{missing.pdf}

\end{document}
```

This gives the error

```
! Package pdfpages Error: Cannot find file `missing.pdf'.

See the pdfpages package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 \includepdf[pages=-]{missing.pdf}
                                     
?
```

If you choose to scroll past the error (effectively what overleaf will do for you) then tex will try to recover but gives a series of spurious internal errors and never terminates

```
! Package pdfpages Error: Cannot find file `missing.pdf'.

See the pdfpages package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 \includepdf[pages=-]{missing.pdf}
                                     
? 

! Package pdfpages Error: Cannot find file `-'.

See the pdfpages package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 \includepdf[pages=-]{missing.pdf}
                                     
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\AM@expand@range ...M@i \relax \@tempcntb =\AM@ii 
                                                  \relax \ifnum \@tempcnta <...
l.9 \includepdf[pages=-]{missing.pdf}
                                     
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\AM@expand@range ...M@i \relax \@tempcntb =\AM@ii 
                                                  \relax \ifnum \@tempcnta <...
l.9 \includepdf[pages=-]{missing.pdf}
                                     
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.9 \includepdf[pages=-]{missing.pdf}
                                     
? 
....
```

Always check the log file for errors

[image]

Comment: Overleaf could make this a bit easier to find, I retracted a close vote on the question, but the genral principle of always check the log file does apply, even on Overleaf.

Comment: Why does TeX never terminate here? What about the “that makes 100 errors” barrier?

Comment: @HenriMenke I really didn't look: it's just usual random  unplanned expansion nonsense and evenally after a dozen or so errors gets to `\def\foo{\foo}\foo` and just hangs in a loop. I mailed him and Andreas has fixed the package so it doesn't do that any more.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out what the problem was:
I wrote `\includepdf[pages=-]{Tp12.pdf}` instead of `\includepdf[pages=-]{pdf/Tp12.pdf}` ! It was just that, I forgot to put the file's name before !

Comment: that would give a tex missing file error

Comment: But it didn't !

Comment: Impossible to say as it doesn't correspond to the code or project that you showed

Comment: Oh, sorry I made a mistake by writing "Pdf12" instead of "Tp12" in my answer ^^ It's edited and now corresponds to my code